# Absolute urls in html file - running in server and locally

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, google-chrome, iis

I have set absolute paths for images in my website. My directory structure is below:

Root

```
 Client

 -- Images
     ---a.png

 -- Index.html
```

so if I use a.png in Index.html I set the src as "/client/Images/a.png". Now this all works fine in the server. But since all my files are pure html I have lost the liberty of just double clicking and running the html files. In this case the paths are broken. I understand the reason for that - how will the browser know what is my root directory? Is there any way to work it around so that it runs both ways or will I always need to run it with some external tool?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to have your URLs be both local and absolute at the same time?

Comment: Yes. Is it not possible to run it at both places without changing anything?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what's going on without seeing your HTML source, but you should be able to use relative URLs.

So if you want to access /Client/Images/a.png from your /Client/Index.html page, you would use a URL like "./Images/a.png" for your image.

The dot at the beginning is saying to start in our current directory, and then look for the subdirectory "Images" for the file "a.png".  You can also use ".." to tell it to look at the parent directory if you need to go up one or more levels, such as if you had to access something in your Client folder.